# trying to display information from xml with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, search-engine, livesearch

just want to set up a search engine like netflix or google which updates my webpages with results without refreshing. therefore i have tried a lot and this is my code. but the code stops at the first entry of xml and i dont know why.

this is my html

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>The best films from 1990 to 1999<h1>


    <table id="demo"></table>

    Search for movie: 
<input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="loadXml()">

    <script>
function loadXml() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "mediathek.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Film</th><th>Year</th><th>Director</th><th>Length</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("film");
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var size = input.length;


  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) 
  { 
     startString = name.substring(0,size);


        if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase())



        {
            name=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            year=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            director=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("director")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            length=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("length")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            description=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;    
            divText = "<h1>The film details are:</h1><br /><table border=1><tr><th>Name</th><th>Year</th><th>Director</th><th>Length</th><th>Description</th></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + year + "</td><td>" + director + "</td><td>" + length + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" + "</table>";
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            divText = divText + "<h2>The film does not exist.</h2>";

        }
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= divText; 




}
</script>


    <div id="results" />

    </body>
</html>
```

and this is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>



<mediathek>

    <films>

        <film label="Pulp Fiction">
            <name>Pulp Fiction</name>
            <year>1994</year>
            <director>Quentin Tarantino</director>
            <length>154</length>
            <description>The lives of two mob hit men, a boxer, a gangster's wife, and a pair of diner bandits intertwine in four tales of violence and redemption.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Blair Witch Project">
            <name>The Blair Witch Project</name>
            <year>1999</year>
            <director>Daniel Myrick, Eduardo Sanchez</director>
            <length>81</length>
            <description>Three film students vanish after traveling into a Maryland forest to film a documentary on the local Blair Witch legend, leaving only their footage behind.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Shawshank Redemption">
            <name>The Shawshank Redemption</name>
            <year>1994</year>
            <director>Frank Darabont</director>
            <length>142</length>
            <description>Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Saving Private Ryan">
            <name>Saving Private Ryan</name>
            <year>1998</year>
            <director>Steven Spielberg</director>
            <length>169</length>
            <description>Following the Normandy Landings, a group of U.S. soldiers go behind enemy lines to retrieve a paratrooper whose brothers have been killed in action.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Wedding Singer">
            <name>The Wedding Singer</name>
            <year>1998</year>
            <director>Frank Coraci</director>
            <length>95</length>
            <description>Robbie, a singer, and Julia, a waitress, are both engaged, but to the wrong people. Fortune intervenes to help them discover each other.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Fight Club">
            <name>Fight Club</name>
            <year>1999</year>
            <director>David Fincher</director>
            <length>139</length>
            <description>An insomniac office worker, looking for a way to change his life, crosses paths with a devil-may-care soap maker, forming an underground fight club that evolves into something much, much more.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Titanic">
            <name>Titanic</name>
            <year>1997</year>
            <director>James Cameron</director>
            <length>194</length>
            <description>A seventeen-year-old aristocrat falls in love with a kind but poor artist aboard the luxurious, ill-fated R.M.S. Titanic.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Forrest Gump">
            <name>Forrest Gump</name>
            <year>1994</year>
            <director>Robert Zemeckis</director>
            <length>142</length>
            <description>Forrest Gump, while not intelligent, has accidentally been present at many historic moments, but his true love, Jenny Curran, eludes him.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="American Pie">
            <name>American Pie</name>
            <year>1999</year>
            <director>Paul Weitz, Chris Weitz</director>
            <length>95</length>
            <description>Four teenage boys enter a pact to lose their virginity by prom night.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Independence Day">
            <name>Independence Day</name>
            <year>1996</year>
            <director>Roland Emmerich</director>
            <length>145</length>
            <description>The aliens are coming and their goal is to invade and destroy Earth. Fighting superior technology, mankind's best weapon is the will to survive.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Goodfellas">
            <name>Goodfellas</name>
            <year>1990</year>
            <director>Martin Scorsese</director>
            <length>146</length>
            <description>Henry Hill and his friends work their way up through the mob hierarchy.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="American Beauty">
            <name>American Beauty</name>
            <year>1999</year>
            <director>Sam Mendes</director>
            <length>122</length>
            <description>A sexually frustrated suburban father has a mid-life crisis after becoming infatuated with his daughter's best friend.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Schindler's List">
            <name>Schindler's List</name>
            <year>1993</year>
            <director>Steven Spielberg</director>
            <length>195</length>
            <description>In German-occupied Poland during World War II, Oskar Schindler gradually becomes concerned for his Jewish workforce after witnessing their persecution by the Nazi Germans.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Usual Suspects">
            <name>The Usual Suspects</name>
            <year>1995</year>
            <director>Bryan Singer</director>
            <length>106</length>
            <description>A sole survivor tells of the twisty events leading up to a horrific gun battle on a boat, which begin when five criminals meet at a seemingly random police lineup.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Silence of the Lambs">
            <name>The Silence of the Lambs</name>
            <year>1991</year>
            <director>Jonathan Demme</director>
            <length>118</length>
            <description>A young F.B.I. cadet must confide in an incarcerated and manipulative killer to receive his help on catching another serial killer who skins his victims.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Big Lebowski">
            <name>The Big Lebowski</name>
            <year>1998</year>
            <director>Joel Coen, Ethan Coen</director>
            <length>117</length>
            <description>"The Dude" Lebowski, mistaken for a millionaire Lebowski, seeks restitution for his ruined rug and enlists his bowling buddies to help get it.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="The Matrix">
            <name>The Matrix</name>
            <year>1999</year>
            <director>Lana Wachowski, Lilly Wachowski</director>
            <length>136</length>
            <description>A computer hacker learns from mysterious rebels about the true nature of his reality and his role in the war against its controllers.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Leon: The Professional">
            <name>Leon: The Professional</name>
            <year>1994</year>
            <director>Luc Besson</director>
            <length>110</length>
            <description>Mathilda, a 12-year-old girl, is reluctantly taken in by Léon, a professional assassin, after her family is murdered. Léon and Mathilda form an unusual relationship, as she becomes his protégée and learns the assassin's trade.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Beauty and the Beast">
            <name>Beauty and the Beast</name>
            <year>1991</year>
            <director>Gary Trousdale, Kirk Wise</director>
            <length>84</length>
            <description>Belle, whose father is imprisoned by the Beast, offers herself instead, unaware her captor to be an enchanted prince.</description>
        </film>

        <film label="Se7en">
            <name>Se7en</name>
            <year>1995</year>
            <director>David Fincher</director>
            <length>127</length>
            <description>Two detectives, a rookie and a veteran, hunt a serial killer who uses the seven deadly sins as his modus operandi.</description>
        </film>



    </films>    

</mediathek>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a break statement after you find a matching film, so the loop never goes through the remaining films.

```js
        function loadXml() {
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              myFunction(this.responseXML);
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "mediathek.xml", true);
          xhttp.send();
        }

        function myFunction(xmlDoc) {
          var tableHead = "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Year</th><th>Director</th><th>Length</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
          var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("film");
          var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
          var size = input.length;
          var filmFound = false;
          var divText = "";
          var tableRows = "";
          var name, year, director, length, description, startString;

          if (input.length < 1) return;

          for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            name = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            startString = name.substring(0, size);

            if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase()) {
              filmFound = true;
              year = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("year")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              director = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("director")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              length = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("length")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              description = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
              tableRows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + year + "</td><td>" + director + "</td><td>" + length + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>";
            }
          }

          if (filmFound) {
            divText = "<h1>The film details are:</h1><br /><table border=1>" + tableHead + tableRows + "</table>";
          } else {
            divText = "<h2>The film does not exist.</h2>";
          }
          document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = divText;
        }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>The best films from 1990 to 1999</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table id="demo"></table>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Search for movie:
  <input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="loadXml()">
</div>
<div class="container" id="results"></div>
```